# SceneBuilder, How drag and drop node into a custom control. [JAVAFX]

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

### Question

My question is relatively simple, I created a **custom control** and I would like to drag and drop "Nodes" from "SceneBuilder" inside it. (See the image below)

#### For example

`public class CustomControl extends Control {}`

I create a "StackPane" then I add my control inside, then inside it I add another "StackPane"

- StackPane

  - CustomControl

    - StackPane

#### JavaFx Example

You can look this class to give you an idea of what I am trying to do.

`public class SplitPane extends Control {}`

[SplitPane JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html)

Or this one :

`public class TitledPane extends Labeled {}`

[TitledPane JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TitledPane.html)

### Environment

My Scene builder version : 8.5.0 [Gluon]

My Java version : 1.8.0_191 [Oracle]

### Custom control exemple

Don't forget it's a **simple example**

```
@DefaultProperty("contentProperty")
public class CrushPane extends Control {
    // Fields

    private ObjectProperty<Node> contentProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "contentProperty");

    // Constructor

    public CrushPane() {
        this(null);
    }


    public CrushPane(Node content) {
        setContent(content);
    }

    // Getters and Setters

    public Node getContent() {
        return contentProperty.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Node> contentProperty() {
        return contentProperty;
    }

    public void setContent(Node content) {
        contentProperty.set(content);
    }

    // Override methods

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new CrushPaneSkin(this);
    }
}
```

The skin

```
public class CrushPaneSkin extends SkinBase<CrushPane> {
    //-----------------------------------------------
    //Fields

    private final ChangeListener<Node> contentChanged = (ob, o, n) -> onContentChanged(n);

    private AnchorPane root;

    //-----------------------------------------------
    //Constructor

    public CrushPaneSkin(CrushPane crushPane) {
        super(crushPane);

        this.root = new AnchorPane();

        getChildren().add(this.root);

        crushPane.contentProperty().addListener(contentChanged);
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------
    //Events

    private void onContentChanged(Node newValue) {
        ObservableList<Node> children = root.getChildren();

        children.clear();

        if (newValue != null) {
            children.add(newValue);

            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(newValue, 0.0d);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(newValue, 0.0d);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(newValue, 0.0d);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(newValue, 0.0d);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the jar into scenebuilder.

### Into Scene builder

[Image when i try to drag a StackPane into my custom control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbIPl.png)

### Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Just a guess here, but I think your custom control either needs to be an extension of Parent or some other node who can have children. For example Parent, StackPane, Pane, HBox, VBox and many more. I guess that means nodes that are a subclass of Parent. Like I said, I am guessing so this may not work at all in SceneBuilder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but a node that extends "control" can have children.

As the class "SplitPane extends Control" and "TitledPane extends Labeled"

Comment: Is there a reason for extending `Control`? See what happens if you extend `Parent`.

Comment: Well, I think that extending the "control" class  allow me to fully customize the skin and behavior of the new component.
Whereas extending the "parent" class wouldn't give me the flexibility needed to position a "son" class wherever I want in a tree.

Comment: Well truly I am out of my league.